# ruby(1.9.3) on rails(3.2.3) Activerecord-odbc-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, odbc

I have a legacy database(Progress OpenEdge) that i need to use for a myriad of reports. I have everything working with ruby 1.8.6 and rails 2.0 (odbc-adapter and odbc-rails).

Since 1.8.6 is not supported anymore and rails 2.0 is quite old i'd like to update. Is there a odbc-adapter supported on 3.2.3?

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an ODBC or ActiveRecord answer for you, but I thought you might be interested in an [OpenEdge adapter for DataMapper](http://blog.abevoelker.com/final-ode-to-openedge-abl-part-1-a-ruby-adapter-is-born/) I wrote.  You'd have to switch to JRuby (it uses the JDBC driver) and the [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) ORM, but you can definitely do Rails 3+ (`dm-rails` gem) with it.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the following line in your gemfile: gem 'ruby-odbc' and then run bundle install.

i think this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Did you had somethin about my answer or was it just useless?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem except am using a legacy database called DBISAM from Elevate Software.

DBISAM does not support a lot of things. But I need to update things on the database and am not a wWindows ecosystem enthusiast.

I will look at `ruby-odbc` and report back to y'all

**EDIT**
I found using RDBI fixed my problem. `gem rdbi`

Comment: Okay, I found that using `gem dbi` is not a good idea as it's not maintained and its heavy.
My solution was to use the lighter and maintained `gem rdbi` and everything worked.

So check https://github.com/RDBI/rdbi