# How to connect to SQLServer 2000 with Rails 3.1.X or higher?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Ive tryed to connect my rails app to a mssql server which is running in version 2000. It cant update the sqlserver because its not mine. I tried using the `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` but Its not working with verion 2000 anymore and Version 2.3.X of the gem does support 2000 but isnt working with Rails above Version 2.3 so,... how can I get it working with my mssql server?

Comment: Use ODBC as a generic intermediate...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337051/ruby1-9-3-on-rails3-2-3-activerecord-odbc-adapter

Comment: That would be great but I dont think theres an odbc driver for mssql 2000 server theres just one for 2008 and 2012.

Comment: When installing MSSQL2000, also a ODBC driver is installed using Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 2.6.

Comment: Yes but I need them for linux not for windows,...